# How can i show an element above the bottom-tabs?

Tags: react-native

[I would like to achieve something similar to what is seen in YouTube Music, but unfortunately, I have been stuck on this part for quite some time. I don't want to use position absolute,'cause I want it to be treated as one object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZKw7.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Profile from "./screens/Profile";
import MiniPlayer from "./components/MiniPlayer";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomTab() {
    return (
        <>
            <MiniPlayer />
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
                <Tab.Screen name="profile" component={Profile} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: But specifically what's your problem ?

Comment: I want to create a sticky component above the tabs and under the screen.

Comment: I found the solution, finally :D

`
import { BottomTabBar } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
export default function BottomTab() {
    return (
        <>
            <Tab.Navigator
                tabBar={(props) => (
                    <View>
                        <MiniPlayer />
                        <BottomTabBar {...props} />
                    </View>
                )}>
                <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
                <Tab.Screen name="profile" component={Profile} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </>
    );
}
`